# Custom target filename for OpenSSL 1.1.1 binaries on Windows

Tags: windows, build, openssl, rename, configure

Since name of the output/target binaries that get built by the makefile as per the build process described on the [wiki page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Configure_Options) remain same irrespective of the options set on the configure command

```
perl Configure (--debug) (no-threads)
```

Is there a way to set different name of the binaries produced by the makefile (e.g. different name for release vs debug binaries or single vs multi-threaded)?